# How to include sticky session in AWS Elastic Beanstalk using Cloud Formation template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, session-cookies, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, sticky

As I searched for the stickiness in Elastic Beanstalk I didn't find the way how to include it using AWS Cloud Formation. Can anyone help me to do that thing.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If we see the definition of sticky sessions, it says "Sticky sessions are a mechanism to route requests to the same target in a target group".

In Elastic Beanstalk, a target group is represented by a process. So we need to set up stickiness at process level using [option settings](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options-general.html#command-options-general-environmentprocess)

You can take 2 approaches here : ( below is for "default" process, if you have configured additional processes then modify accordingly but implementation remains same )

option setting namespace : aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:process:default
Valid options to set : StickinessEnabled, StickinessLBCookieDuration

1. Specify option settings in your CloudFormation template under the [AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Environment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-beanstalk-environment.html) Type, like described.

sample :

```
"Environment": {
  "Properties": {
    "ApplicationName": {
      "Ref": "Application"
    },
    "Description": "AWS Elastic Beanstalk Environment running Python Sample Application",
    "SolutionStackName": {
      "Ref": "SolutionStackName"
    },
    "VersionLabel": "Initial Version",
    "OptionSettings": [
      {
        "Namespace": "aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:process:default",
        "OptionName": "StickinessEnabled",
        "Value":"true"
      },
      {
        "Namespace": "aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:process:default",
        "OptionName": "StickinessLBCookieDuration",
        "Value":"43200"
      }
    ]
  },
  "Type": "AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Environment"
}
```

2. Configure this at the source bundle level, i.e, create a .config file ( say albstickiness.config ) and place it in .ebextensions folder. In the .config file set stickiness for the ALB process.

sample can be found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environments-cfg-alb.html) under the sub heading ".ebextensions/alb-default-process.config"

Answer (score 1):

you can try the below

```
      LBCookieStickinessPolicy:
      - PolicyName: myLBPolicy
        CookieExpirationPeriod: '180'
```

you can read more about the sticky session [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environments-cfg-alb.html) and [here](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-cloudformation-templates/blob/master/aws/services/ElasticLoadBalancing/ELBStickinessSample.yaml)

Comment: When I tried this, I got an error as below in CloudFormation. And I am not able to create stack using this.
"Encountered unsupported property LBCookieStickinessPolicy"

Comment: Which load balancer you are using?

Comment: Application load balancer