# AWS: Configure EC2 environment to receive all the requests from a user session (booking system) to the same EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a Java struts-2 based booking system deployed on AWS with free-tier Elastic Beanstalk. Currently, the user request from a session sometimes lands on different EC2 instances due to traffic and this creates a problem with session variables being empty. How should I configure the EC2 instance/environment so that the request from a user/browser session always goes to the same instance?

Comment: I don't think EB can be configured with session affinity to a particular EC2 instance since it PaaS, but latest version of EB may very well now have that feature.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to include sticky session in AWS Elastic Beanstalk using Cloud Formation template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57954913/how-to-include-sticky-session-in-aws-elastic-beanstalk-using-cloud-formation-tem)